# Białynicki-Birula decomposition for singular projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let us have a (possibly singular) irreducible projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, with an algebraic $\mathbb{C}^*$-action that has finitely many fixed points $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$. One can define the attracting sets 
$$U_k = \{x \in X \mathrel| \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}t\cdot x =x_k\}$$ that decompose $X$ into a disjoint union. When $X$ is smooth, Białynicki-Birula's theorem is that these are affine bundles over $x_k$, hence affine spaces. That gives us an affine cell decomposition of $X$.

> Is this still true when $X$ is singular?

Comment: Maybe you want to add the hypothesis that $X$ is irreducible ? (else there are easy counterexamples).

Comment: Oh, I was hoping to get away without putting the irreducibility hypothesis. Which counterexamples do you have in mind? (I am not an algebraic geometer, sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: No, take a toric variety and the action of a randomly chosen rank one subtorus. You will get toric singularities in the cells.

Comment: @Filip92 : You can take 2 $\Bbb P^1$ touching at a point, and take the torus action so that the commun vertex is attracting for both action.

Comment: There are *some* results, just not as nice, e.g., decomposition is not into affine spaces; but maybe it is still useful for you? For instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2604 is for $G_m$ action on algebraic spaces of finite type; https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matpur.2019.04.006 generalizes it to actions of reductive groups.

Comment: I see, thank you all! To be completely precise, I did not need an affine cell decomposition, but rather a vanishing result $$H_{odd}(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$$ for singular homology of $X$ in odd degrees (which would follow from an affine cell decomposition).

Comment: @Filip92 : it's still wrong in the non-irreducible case (you can take $3$ $\Bbb P^1$ forming a triangle that will give you a non-trivial $H^1$)

Comment: @Filip92: I thought a little about your revised version of the question. One still has a BB decomposition into contratible pieces indexed by the fixed points, but I can't see whether / how one can use this to show the vanishing you want. My gut feeling is that the answer is no, but I couldn't find a counter-example. If the question is still interesting you could make a new question about this ...

Comment: Here is another modified question, which I have been working about for more than 15 years: under what circumstances is $U_x $ irreducible?  For example if $ X $ is a Springer fibre it is, but if $ X $ is an spherical Schubert variety, it is not generally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not at all. Take any Schubert variety, $X_w \subset G/B$. Then for one choice of $\mathbb{C}^* \subset T$ the BB decomposition is a cell decomposition, but for others (e.g., when the Schubert variety is singular and the torus is chosen to be attractive at the "base point" $B/B$) it will not be.

The simplest example is probably given by a singular quadric cone in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with unique singular point $x$. This has many $\mathbb{C}^*$-actions which are attractive near $x$ with finitely many fixed points, and hence the attractive set is a singular affine quadric.

My guess is that it is a miracle when it is, and studying singular examples shows how amazing it is that it holds in the smooth case.

PS: I just did the classic "read the comments after drafting an answer" and I see that Piotr ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356995/bialynicki-birula-decomposition-for-singular-projective-variety#comment897317_356995)) and Nicolas ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356995/bialynicki-birula-decomposition-for-singular-projective-variety#comment897251_356995) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356995/bialynicki-birula-decomposition-for-singular-projective-variety#comment897319_356995) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356995/bialynicki-birula-decomposition-for-singular-projective-variety#comment897591_356995)) have already answered the question. Posting anyway in case it helps someone someday ….