# Plus and minus Białynicki-Birula decomposition for normal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, torus-action

We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a normal projective irreducible variety, and let $\mathbb{C}^*$ act nontrivially on $X$. The fixed point locus of $X$, namely $X^{\mathbb{C}^*}$, can be decomposed into a disjoint union of connected fixed point components, let us call them $F_1,\ldots,F_s$. Moreover, for any $k=1,\ldots,s$, we can define the *plus* cell
as

$$X^+(F_k)=\{p\in X\mid \lim_{t\to 0} t\cdot p \in F_k\}$$

and similarly also the *minus* cell, by considering the limit at $\infty$.

If $X$ is smooth, then the celebrated theorem of Bialynicki-Birula tell us that
\begin{equation}
X=\bigsqcup_{i=1\ldots k} X^+(F_k)\tag{*}\label{star}
\end{equation}
(and similarly for the minus cell), and moreover this is an affince cell decomposition.

**Question:** If $X$ is only normal, do we still have a decomposition as in \eqref{star} (but in this case the cell will not be afine, as explained in [Białynicki-Birula decomposition for singular projective variety](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356995/bia%C5%82ynicki-birula-decomposition-for-singular-projective-variety))?

I've tried to search on the literature, but what I've found is usually much more deep of what I'm asking and I have a hard time trying to translate that result in my specific case. Any help, or reference, would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your question, did you intend to write, "If $X$ is only normal, ..."?

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr, sure, thanks for spotting the typo!

Comment: Have you looked at Hausel-Hitchin arXiv:2101.08583, Section 2.1?

Comment: Such a generalization is I think due to Drinfeld and employed in several papers by Jelisiejew.

Comment: The references: arXiv:1308.2604 (Drinfeld), arXiv:1710.06124 (Jelisiejew, see Section 3), arXiv:1805.11558 (generalization to reductive groups, Jelisiejew-Sienkiewicz)

Comment: Dear @Balazs, I didn't know that reference, thank you very much for pointing it out. However at a first glance it doesn't seems to me that they justify the partition they give in Definition 2.8: maybe it is trivial, I'll try to read it carefully

Comment: Dear @PiotrAchinger, thank you for the reply. I am aware of these references and I've tried other times to look at them, unfortunately for me it's a bit difficult to keep track of their construction and see if at the end they provide the answer I'm looking for (also because I don't think my question need that level of depth to be answered). I'll try one more time, thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Which statement are you wondering about?  The fact that the number of fixed point components is finite or the fact that every point of $ X $ belongs to $ X^+(F_k) $ for some $ k$?

Comment: Dear @JoelKamnitzer, the second one, that is the existence of a decomposition. I have thought naively about taking a point, not fixed, consider its orbit and take the limit (so that it will land at a fixed component), but 1- may it happen that that orbit ramifies, and the limit belong to 2 different component? 2- can I still take consider extend the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action to a $\mathbb{P}^1$-action? 3- is there something elsse I should worry about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, \eqref{star} is always a disjoint union (that's obvious). Moreover, each set $X^+(F_k)$ is locally closed and the map $x\mapsto\lim_{t\to0}t\cdot x$ induces an affine morphism $\pi_k:X^+(F_k)\to F_k$. In general, the morphism $\pi_k$ is not a fiber bundle anymore.

These assertions can be easily reduced to the smooth case by using a theorem of Sumihiro (Sumihiro, Hideyasu: [Equivariant completion](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250523277). J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 14 (1974), 1–28) according to which $X$ can be embedded equivariantly into a projective space.

The assertions are more generally valid for any normal complete variety. The paper "Konarski, Jerzy: Decompositions of normal algebraic varieties determined by an action of a one-dimensional torus.
Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. 26 (1978), 295–300" seems to be a good reference.

Comment: Dear Prof. Knop, thank you very much for the answer and the references. Before accepting it though, I have few questions. You say at the beginning "it's obvious": are you referring to the fact that the union is disjoint (and I agree with you on this), or are you referring to the fact that $X$ coincides with the union? I was precisely asking about the second point, but with your suggestion I think I know how to prove the second question (see the comment below):

Comment: Using Sumihiro's theorem, we embed $X$ $\mathbb{C}^*$-equivariantly into a $\mathbb{P}^n$. Now we use the BB-decomposition of the projective space, obtaining $$\mathbb{P}^n=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^k (\mathbb{P}^n)^+(F_i),$$
where $F_i$ are the connected fixed point components of $\mathbb{P}^n$ under the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action. Then since $X$ is $\mathbb{C}^*$-invariant we consider the intersection of the BB-decomposition with $X$, obtaining
$$\mathbb{P}^n\cap X=X=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^k X^+(F_i\cap X),$$
where maybe some intersection will be empty, but we still obtain a $+$-decomposition of $X$.

Comment: @Mago: That's correct. That $(*)$ is a disjoint union follows from the fact that for every $x$ the limit $\lim_{t\to0} t\cdot x$ exists (since $X$ is complete) and is unique (since $X$ is separated) and that the limit point is a $\mathbb C^*$-fixed point. But all this follows also from the Sumihiro argument once you accept the assertions for the projective space.

Comment: @Mako: One more thing: Observe that $F_i\cap X$ might have several connected components. Then $X^+(F_i\cap X)$ decoposes accordingly.

Comment: Dear Prof. Knop, I see. Thank you very much for the clear explanation!